# ASP.NET Web API - Change database application is running to based on HTTP header information

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have started a new Web API project that requires that we switch the database the application is running to based on HTTP header information sent to the API. The application user will be identified by a HTTP header and the application should then change to use their database.

I have a base controller `CrudControllerBase<T>` ( to handle simple generic HTTP requests ) which creates a `DataService<T>` in it's constructor. All of my controllers will derive from this base controller and will have access to this DataService. The `DataService` is used to do common DB queries ( FindById(), FindAll(), etc. ) and more complex queries are bolted on using extension methods.

```
public abstract class CrudControllerBase<T> : ApiController where T : class, IEntity
{
    protected IDataService<T> _dataService;

    public CrudControllerBase()
    {
        this._dataService = new DataService<T>();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public virtual async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(Guid id)
    {
        var model = await _dataService.FindByIdAsync(id);
        return Ok<T>(model);
    }

    //code left out
}

public class OrdersController : CrudControllerBase<OrderItem>
    {
    }
```

and in the DataService I new up the DbContext class:

```
public class DataService<T> : IDataService<T> where T:class, IEntity
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _context;

    public DataService()
    {
        _context = new AppDbContext(); // need to pass in connection string
    }

    // code left out
}
```

I need to be able to pass in the connection string to the constructor of AppDbContext but in the constructor of `CrudControllerBase` I do not have access to the HttpRequestMessage to be able to pass this info to the `DataService`.

Can anyone suggest a solution ? I am quite happy to try a completely different way of doing this if someone can suggest something. Thanks !

Comment: You might be able to create a Custom controller factory, either encapsulating or inheriting from the DefaultControllerFactory, as there is an overload that takes the RequestContext and then you could give your controller constructors a parameter: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=878

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I have got this working. It may not be the best solution but it works and if anyone has any feedback / improvements then please share. Thanks to @AaronLS for pointing me in the right direction. This [article](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/09/28/DependencyInjectionandLifetimeManagementwithASP.NETWebAPI/) also helped a lot.

The first step was to create a `CustomControllerFactory` that implements the `IHttpControllerActivator` interface. This gives you a `Create` method in which you can write your own code for newing up your Controllers. This is my `CustomControllerFactory` where I new up my controller passing in the HTTP Header as a string:

```
public class CustomControllerFactory : IHttpControllerActivator
{
    public IHttpController Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
    {
        var schemaKey = request.Headers.Where(k => k.Key == "schema").FirstOrDefault().Value.FirstOrDefault();
        return (IHttpController)Activator.CreateInstance(controllerType, new string[] { schemaKey });
    }
}
```

The next step is to tell the web API to use this method for instantiating controllers. To do this I added this line to my `WebApiConfig` class:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerActivator), new CustomControllerFactory());
```

The last thing I needed to was add a constructor to each controller which took in the string value and passed it to the base controller

```
public OrdersController(String databaseName) : base(databaseName) { }
```

and my base controller passes the parameter to the `DataService`

```
public CrudControllerBase(String databaseName)
{
    this._dataService = new DataService<T>(databaseName);
}
```

and my database passes in the connection string to the AppDbContext() constructor

```
public DataService(String databaseName)
{
    this._context = new AppDbContext(BuildConnectionString(databaseName));
}
```

I realise there is no error handling / security checking yet but I will add that in :-)

Comment: i have similar scenario, where user has a dropdown containing list of connection name to select from. After selection entity framework has to use that database connection till user logout. i have create a custom class  that generates connection string to pass as parameter in entities constructor. You can check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42924607/alternative-of-session-to-store-information-web-api-asp-net-project . Help needed